# Electron modal javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am learning to create apps using electron. So far I have a `main.js` file running on the main process, and then I have an `index.js` for my `index.html` page, and I have a modal popup `add.html` which uses an `add.js` file. I have 2 buttons in my `add.html` file and I can't get either of them to work no matter what method I use. I have tried using the following methods to use the button:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Add Room</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/add.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <p class="name">Address: </p> -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="address">
            <input class="nameVal" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="add"> Add </button>
            <button id="cancelBtn" class="cancel" onclick="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <a id="close">Close</a> -->
    <script  src="./add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;
const currWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

let cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelBtn');
var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
//This method is used in index.js and it works perfectly.
$(".cancel").forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("this thing is doinh stuuffff");
    });
});

cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("this thing is doing stufff");
});

function cancelButton() {
    alert("this thing is using the onclick property");
}
```

I know that my html is linking to my javascript because if I make the javascript popup an alert without using a button it works.

I have seen other posts with a similar problem, but their issue was fixed because they had a typo. I re-wrote and re-read my code multiple times over the course of a few days, so I doubt that the issue is due to a typo.

`add.html` is used as a modal window, so maybe there are some rules that I'm missing about modal windows? But its called from `main.js` using `icp` and it works fine:

```
ipc.on('open-add-room-window', () => {
  var addRoom = new BrowserWindow({parent: win, modal: true, width: 300, height: 150, resizable: false, show: false});
  addRoom.loadFile("src/add.html");
  addRoom.on('close', () => { addRoom = null; });
  addRoom.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    addRoom.show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Is `cancelBtn` not `undefined`?

Comment: heya, did you enable the nodeIntegration when you are creating browserWindow?

Comment: @MoshFeu There are no errors popping up, so the button should be defined.

Comment: @tpikachu Yes, node integration is enabled.

Comment: you are using jQuery?

Comment: //This method is used in index.js and it works perfectly. what do you mean?

Comment: anyhow everything is working fine, when I click the cancel button then it is showing 2 alerts at my machine good

Comment: @tpikachu I mean that the same approach is used in the javascript file for my main window, and it works there. I don't remember installing jQuery, so I don't think I'm using it, unless somehow it installed with electron? I'm not sure i'm somewhat new to javascript.

Comment: @tpikachu Actually, I just enabled nodeIntegration on my modal BrowserWindow and it worked! Sorry, I misunderstood your original question and thought you were asking about it being enabled on the main window. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tpikachu I was able to solve the issue by enabling `nodeIntegration` on my modal `BrowserWindow` using the following code:

```
var addRoom = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}, parent: win, modal: true, width: 300, height: 150, resizable: false, show: false});
```